# I try to connect to ergo irc to the mySQL

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, irc

I tried to get history data of the chat from ergo(irc).

In the ergo documentation i can use mysql for to get the history of the chat.
[Ergo](https://github.com/ergochat/ergo/blob/master/docs/MANUAL.md#persistent-history-with-mysql)

[ergo documentation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2rE0l.png)

I do the steps for mysql and i see all the table have from ergo.
But no have data inside maybe i missed something, maybe i need to connect the mysql to the ergo docker ?
Someone did it and can help me?
I add image how i was setup the mysql
[mysql setup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G7eD6.png)

Also i was create a node.js server to listen to events maybe in the server i need to setup for to get history data from the ergo?

[this is the mysql setup on the ircd.yaml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AjKZz.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I added the setup of the ircd.yaml file